# Dynamically creating a function that is called when an image is selected using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically displaying selectable images on a page using jQuery. When I select the image the console displays an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: MTU4 is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (AwardsEdit.html:1)". This is what is called:

"getAwardDetailsFunction(MTU4)".

jQuery:

```
contents += '<figure>';
contents += '<a href="#" onclick="getAwardDetailsFunction('+obj.awardId+')">';
contents += '<img id="awardImage'+obj.awardId+'" src="' + obj.awardPicture + '" alt="Award image" class="img-thumbnail">';
```

I have tried putting quotes around the variable MTU4 using:

```
contents += '<figure>';
contents += '<a href="#" onclick="getAwardDetailsFunction('+'\\"'+obj.awardId+'\\"'+')">';
contents += '<img id="awardImage'+obj.awardId+'" src="' + obj.awardPicture + '" alt="Award image" class="img-thumbnail">';
```

This gives me the error "AwardsEdit.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" in the console.

The function being called is:

```
function getAwardDetailsFunction(awardID) {

    alert("awardID: " + awardID)

    sessionStorage.setItem('ssAwardID', awardID);

    window.location = "AwardUpdate.html";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have spend days on this and then just after posting I found the answer:

Replace:

```
contents += '<a href="#" onclick="getAwardDetailsFunction('+obj.awardId+')">';
```

With:

```
contents += '<a href="#" onclick="getAwardDetailsFunction(\'' + obj.awardId.replace('\'', '&quot;') + '\')"</a>';
```